# REST API response is huge

Tags: node.js, api, https, xmlhttprequest, cryptocurrency

I am required to request an API endpoint that returns a huge historical dataset from 2015.

However, I am having issues with data.

When I use the request library it takes time to return the dataset and the docs show the following:

```
const https = require('https');

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "rest.coinapi.io",
  "path": "/v1/ohlcv/BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD/history?period_id=1MIN&time_start=2016-01-01T00:00:00",
  "headers": {'X-CoinAPI-Key': '73034021-0EBC-493D-8A00-E0F138111F41'}
};

var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
  var chunks = [];
  response.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });
});

request.end();
```

How do I create an async function that awaits the response and then writes the complete response onto a file(using `fs` module) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your whole thing with a `Promise` and resolve it when you're done with your data (which means `.on('end')`) :

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "rest.coinapi.io",
  "path": "/v1/ohlcv/BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD/history?period_id=1MIN&time_start=2016-01-01T00:00:00",
  "headers": {'X-CoinAPI-Key': '73034021-0EBC-493D-8A00-E0F138111F41'}
};

const getMyDataAsync = opts => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
  https.request(opts, response => {
    const chunks = [];
    response.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
    response.on('end', () => resolve(chunks));
    response.on('error', err => reject(err));
  })
);
```

now you can use the promise, with then or async :

```
try {
  const myData = await getMyDataAsync(options);
} catch(e) { /* handle error here */ }
```

**OR**

```
getMyDataAsync(options)
  .then(myData => { /* your data is right here */ })
  .catch(e => { /* handle error here */ })
```

Comment: I get this error `events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)`